# How can I store the same autoincrementing ID in two different tables automatically?

Tags: html, mysql

So, the thing is:

I'm building a online marketplace and it has several stores in the same marketplace, for that I want to ID each store and  each product they have, the thing is I have a form where they answer it all and it redirects the data to a sql relational database.

So, for example:

```
The form could be something like this ( I'm still thinking how I'm going to do this ):

    name           
    product1 /  price
    product2 /  price
       .
       .
       .
    productN /  price


    And the database having this base structure:

    STORES            PRODUCTS              STORE/PRODUCT          
    -----------       -----------           --------------    
    ID  name:         Pcode  Pname:         ID    PID    Price         
    1   store1        100    product1       1     101    50$ 
    2   store2        101    product2       1     103    20$
    3   store3        102    product3       2     103    25$

(ID is autoincrementing )
```

So, in this form the store manager would insert all the data he needs and this data is placed on my mysql table.

The problem is:

I'm not seeing how I'm going to insert the same ID in several different tables since the ID is autoincrementing.

Anyone has a suggestion on a sql command that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

> You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.